# Spring JDBCTemplate Issue with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring

I am trying to execute below query using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

```
String quer = "select cd_lqa_loan_procss_sts from EACSDBO1.lqa_loan_prcsg where DTTM_PROCSS_CMPLT >= to_timestamp(:timestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF')";

MapSqlParameterSource parametersTime = newMapSqlParameterSource();          
parametersTime.addValue("timestamp", targetDeliveryStamp);
```

It throws Exception -ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

But the same query executes fine when I directly pass the timestamp value instead using it as parameter. But i cannot directly pass the java value as it will be a issue with SAST(SQL injection). Can you please suggest what is the issue. As per the error it is format of the timestamp but it works fine without parameter

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to pass it as a parameter? Just use a `?` and plain `JdbcTemplate` offers the same protection. You shouldn't be using String concat as that will indeed enable SQL Injection. Also why are you even passing in a String? Just pass a `Date` instead of trying to let SQL convert a String for the query.

Comment: what do you have in targetDeliveryStamp ? and what is the sentence that execute correctly ?